# Regex/ Substring

Tags: regex, r, substring, bioinformatics

I have a sequence like this in a list `"MSGSRRKATPASRTRVGNYEMGRTLGEGSFAKVKYAKNTVTGDQAAIKILDREKVFRHKMVEQLKREISTMKLIKHPNVVEIIEVMASKTKIYIVLELVNGGELFDKIAQQGRLKEDEARRYFQQLINAVDYCHSRGVYHRDLKPENLILDANGVLKVSDFGLSAFSRQVREDGLLHTACGTPNYVAPEVLSDKGYDGAAADVWSCGVILFVLMAGYLPFDEPNLMTLYKRICKAEFSCPPWFSQGAKRVIKRILEPNPITRISIAELLEDEWFKKGYKPPSFDQDDEDITIDDVDAAFSNSKECLVTEKKEKPVSMNAFELISSSSEFSLENLFEKQAQLVKKETRFTSQRSASEIMSKMEETAKPLGFNVRKDNYKIKMKGDKSGRKGQLSVATEVFEVAPSLHVVELRKTGGDTLEFHKVCDSFYKNFSSGLKDVVWNTDAAAEEQKQ"`

I would like to create a substring like wherever a "K" is present it needs to pull out 6 characters before and 6 characters after "K"

Ex : `MSGSRRKATPASR` , here -6..K..+6

for the whole sequence..I tried the substring function in R but we need to specify the start and end position. Here the positions are unknown

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you have two `K` within 6 letters from each other liike in `LEDEWFKKGYKPP`?

Comment: Relevant post at [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/109077)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.

```
x <- "MSGSRRKATPASRTRVGNYEMGRTLGEGSFAKVKYAKNTVTGDQAAIKILDREKVFRHKMVEQLKREISTMKLIKHPNVVEIIEVMASKTKIYIVLELVNGGELFDKIAQQGRLKEDEARRYFQQLINAVDYCHSRGVYHRDLKPENLILDANGVLKVSDFGLSAFSRQVREDGLLHTACGTPNYVAPEVLSDKGYDGAAADVWSCGVILFVLMAGYLPFDEPNLMTLYKRICKAEFSCPPWFSQGAKRVIKRILEPNPITRISIAELLEDEWFKKGYKPPSFDQDDEDITIDDVDAAFSNSKECLVTEKKEKPVSMNAFELISSSSEFSLENLFEKQAQLVKKETRFTSQRSASEIMSKMEETAKPLGFNVRKDNYKIKMKGDKSGRKGQLSVATEVFEVAPSLHVVELRKTGGDTLEFHKVCDSFYKNFSSGLKDVVWNTDAAAEEQKQ"

library(rex)
re_matches(x,
  rex(
    capture(name = "amino_acids",
      n(any, 6),
      "K",
      n(any, 6)
    )
  ),
  global = TRUE)[[1]]
#>     amino_acids
#>1  MSGSRRKATPASR
#>2  GEGSFAKVKYAKN
#>3  GDQAAIKILDREK
#>4  KMVEQLKREISTM
#>5  IEVMASKTKIYIV
#>6  GGELFDKIAQQGR
#>7  VYHRDLKPENLIL
#>8  DANGVLKVSDFGL
#>9  PEVLSDKGYDGAA
#>10 NLMTLYKRICKAE
#>11 WFSQGAKRVIKRI
#>12 LEDEWFKKGYKPP
#>13 AAFSNSKECLVTE
#>14 LENLFEKQAQLVK
#>15 ASEIMSKMEETAK
#>16 LGFNVRKDNYKIK
#>17 GDKSGRKGQLSVA
#>18 HVVELRKTGGDTL
#>19 VCDSFYKNFSSGL
```

However the above is greedy, each K will only appear in one result.

If you want to output an AA for each K

```
library(rex)
locs <- re_matches(x,
  rex(
    "K" %if_prev_is% n(any, 6) %if_next_is% n(any, 6)
    ),
  global = TRUE, locations = TRUE)[[1]]

substring(x, locs$start - 6, locs$end + 6)
#> [1] "MSGSRRKATPASR" "GEGSFAKVKYAKN" "GSFAKVKYAKNTV" "AKVKYAKNTVTGD"
#> [5] "GDQAAIKILDREK" "KILDREKVFRHKM" "EKVFRHKMVEQLK" "KMVEQLKREISTM"
#> [9] "REISTMKLIKHPN" "STMKLIKHPNVVE" "IEVMASKTKIYIV" "VMASKTKIYIVLE"
#>[13] "GGELFDKIAQQGR" "AQQGRLKEDEARR" "VYHRDLKPENLIL" "DANGVLKVSDFGL"
#>[17] "PEVLSDKGYDGAA" "NLMTLYKRICKAE" "LYKRICKAEFSCP" "WFSQGAKRVIKRI"
#>[21] "GAKRVIKRILEPN" "LEDEWFKKGYKPP" "EDEWFKKGYKPPS" "WFKKGYKPPSFDQ"
#>[25] "AAFSNSKECLVTE" "ECLVTEKKEKPVS" "CLVTEKKEKPVSM" "VTEKKEKPVSMNA"
#>[29] "LENLFEKQAQLVK" "KQAQLVKKETRFT" "QAQLVKKETRFTS" "ASEIMSKMEETAK"
#>[33] "KMEETAKPLGFNV" "LGFNVRKDNYKIK" "VRKDNYKIKMKGD" "KDNYKIKMKGDKS"
#>[37] "NYKIKMKGDKSGR" "IKMKGDKSGRKGQ" "GDKSGRKGQLSVA" "HVVELRKTGGDTL"
#>[41] "DTLEFHKVCDSFY" "VCDSFYKNFSSGL" "NFSSGLKDVVWNT"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.{6}K.{6}
```

Try this.This will give the desired result.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dM0rS8/4

Comment: In order to run this in R, do `regmatches(x, gregexpr(".{6}K.{6}", x, perl = TRUE))` when `x` is the string

Answer (score 4):

use this:

```
\w{7}(?<=K)\w{6}
```

this uses positive lookbehind to ensure that there are characters present before `K`.

demo here:  http://regex101.com/r/pK3jK1/2

Comment: It seems in all of them. It always catche only 5 letters before `K`

Comment: yea I noticed and updated it .. actually the lookbehind doesnt select a character so thats why I should select 7 letters

Comment: In order to run this in R you will do something like `regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\w{7}(?<=K)\\w{6}", x, perl = TRUE))` when `x` is the string. The only thing I don't get is what happens when there are several `K`s within the range of 6 letters

Comment: Thanks David. In case of LEDEWFKKGYKPP .. It could be taken as LEDEWFKKGYKPP or EDEWFKKGYKPP(anycharacter) . I just need different combinations with -6K+6